# How to get directions of freeway using osmnx

Tags: python, openstreetmap, shortest-path, osmnx

I am using osmnx for routing and I would like to know the direction of the freeway the route involves. The following is an example:

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

G = ox.graph_from_place("Los Angeles County, California, USA", network_type="drive")

origin = (33.821642, -118.281422)
destination = (33.876752, -118.055168)
origin_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, origin[1], origin[0])
destination_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, destination[1], destination[0])
route = ox.shortest_path(G, origin_node, destination_node, weight="travel_time")
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_route(G, route, route_color="c", node_size=0)

G.edges[(route[8], route[9], 0)]
```

The following is the output:
{'osmid': [604115924, 604115927],
'oneway': True,
'lanes': '4',
'ref': 'I 110',
'name': 'Harbor Freeway',
'highway': 'motorway',
'reversed': False,
'length': 1232.397,
'geometry': <LINESTRING (-118.287 33.831, -118.287 33.836, -118.287 33.837, -118.287 33....>}

I want to know if the route involves going on I-110 N or I-110 South. From [How to get the direction of roads in osmnx for finding shortest path for an emergency vehicle like ambulance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76193147/how-to-get-the-direction-of-roads-in-osmnx-for-finding-shortest-path-for-an-emer), I know that the value for 'reversed' is False, which means the direction is the same as the default OpenStreetMap direction. However, I was wondering how I could find out the default OpenStreetMap direction, in this case, is it North or South. Otherwise, the value of 'reversed' would be meaningless to me.

Thank you, and any comments will be greatly appreciated.

I've read the post at https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/pull/814, but it does not elaborate on the field of 'reversed'

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to this. You said:

> I would like to know the direction of the freeway

and:

> I want to know if the route involves going on I-110 N or I-110 South

The direction (i.e., bearing) of a route can be derived by the nodes that the edge contains + the `reversed` edge attribute. You can use OSMnx's `bearing` module to calculate the bearing automatically for every edge in the graph.

More specifically to your question, if you want to know if they "I-110" in question is the "I-110 North" or the "I-110 South," you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744482/determining-highway-direction) and this [OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Route_directions) page. The OSMnx `graph` module does not work with relations to create its graph models, but you can download OSM relations using the OSMnx `features` module (though this wouldn't really help you with your graph model).